# How to make a multi-window app in android api 6.0

Tags: android

I find `WeiChat` or other app can open multi-window display on desktop. But I set it refer to google. It doesn't work.

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
```

Please tell me the reason. Thanks.

Comment: isn't multiWindow supported from Android 7.0?

Comment: multi-window  support from Android 7.0 . but i watched some app  is multi-window  from Android 6.0

Comment: I didn't find `weichat` app on google play. Found only `wechat`

Answer (score 0):

Multi window support is established from Android 7.0 only.So u can choose ur API level 7 or above.

Comment: thanks,sir.but you can install a app named weichat .it can  open by multi-window in  android mobile  . for example on  samsung.

Comment: For prior to Android 7.0,The multi window support is not there if it is there in any of app means they will implemented by using some kind of canvas,graphics predefined android api